# Xcode Instruments Time Profiler not accepting dYSM file

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, xcode-instruments

I have been been trying to see the symbols on the Time Profiler instruments whilst running my app. I have successfully created the dYSM file located in my derived data. Every-time I go to Preferences > Symbols and located my dYSM to link to my app, it turns orange but then soon after it'll go back to normal.

I have tried deleting the derived data, I have restarted xcode as well as tried every other method. Could someone please share some light as to why my dYSM file is being rejected.

My build scheme is set to Profile(Release)

Thank you